# How to convert varchar value to numeric

Tags: c#, database, crystal-reports

I have a column in database which is varchar. How can I convert to integer in order to get the sum in crystal report. Will it possible to conver the varchar to numeric when using the stored procedure....

Comment: Why is it stored as a varchar in the first place?

Comment: Also, what database are you using.  Please add tags.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in C# without using Try/Catch:

```
int value = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse("string to parse", out value))
{
    // Value parsed correctly        
}
else
{
    // Could not be parsed.
}
```

You might be better off doing it in the database query though if possible. Also as others have suggested, why is a numeric being stored in a varchar field?

**Edit**

Both [Transact SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [PL/SQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/cast.php) dialects support the `CAST` function.

You could probably do the conversion in the query using - although be aware that there may be subtle differences in the actual database you are using.

```
SELECT ..., CAST(field_name AS int), ... FROM table_name ...
```

Thanks to Anjay for his *most valuable* contributions.

Comment: Here is the question is for crystal report and not C# code. We need something in stored procedure or SQL

Comment: The question was tagged as C#, and I suggested that doing the conversion in the database might be a better approach. The question has still not been tagged with a database type, so it will be difficult to make a suggestion without knowing what database is being targeted :)

Comment: Wasn't when I posted the answer originally, but I have updated it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT , varchar_column)) FROM [test]
```

Comment: What if the value cant be converted? Will this throw an exception?

Answer (score -1):

You use the following functions in Stored procedure or Views and use them in Crystal report which will do the calculation part.

```
SELECT CAST(YourVarcharCol AS INT) FROM Table
or

SELECT CONVERT(INT, YourVarcharCol) FROM Table
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: why down vote? can add the comment why its down voted? It should help me and others to know the reason.